# Anaconda virtual environment django in windows

Tags: django, anaconda

[image: Virtual Environment]

I created a virtual environment using anaconda in windows, and there are a lot of stuff installed within the virtual environment, when I tried to add my project to the github, it listed all the files within the directory to be committed and showed the follow warnings: LF will be replaced by CRLF.

how can I properly set up a virtual envs by using Anaconda3 to start my django project, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your git setting

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

Windows and unix systems use different line breakpoints and this just says that your committing from a windows machine